# Are string versions of variable names available in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I'm watching last year's WWDC on auto layout, session 228. There is this code:

```
NSView *previousView = nil
for (NSView *view in letterViews) {
...
  [NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousView, view);
  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[previousView(==view)]" 
    options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

How do the string values "previousView" and "view" get used here? Can that method actually work out the object from the name?

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, variable names are not available everywhere and anywhere. This is just like C.

Here's what is happening:

`NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` simply uses the preprocessor to turn its parameters into `NSString`s:

```
#define NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(...) \
 _NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(@"" # __VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__, nil)
```

That is to say `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousView, view)` expands to:

```
_NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(@"" "previousView, view", previousView, view, nil)
```

Which could simply create the returned `NSDictionary`'s keys by dividing the string parameter passed to the private function `_NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings`; in this case that parameter expands to `@"previousView, view"`.

Comment: Thanks. Fooled by that old preprocessor again.